# how twitter changed the get question mark on the url

Tags: php, ruby, twitter

i wonder how twitter did their URL like this

> https://twitter.com/#!/twitter

is it a unique method via ruby or it's something i can do with .htaccess and php because as far as i know this # sign is used to send user to a certain block on the page

also is it possible to use
other tags for example & or % or $ etc.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you should read to find out what `#!` means:

1. [A proposal for making AJAX crawlable](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html)
2. [Getting started with `#!`](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html)
3. [Full Specification](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html)
4. [Why it might be not a good idea](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2011/02/09/Hash-Blecch)

However, if you're just doing this for aesthetics because you like `#!` more than `?` or `&`: don't do it. It's not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 2):

They [use JavaScript to read the hash and load content via Ajax](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs)